# How to download custom fonts dynamically in android?

Tags: android, android-fonts

I have a set of custom fonts that are not available in fonts.google.com but I want to download then dynamically. Is there any possible way to do so?

Downloadable Fonts feature doesn't work as the font which I am using is not available in fonts.google.com

Answer (score -2):

download fonts from any website here is one
https://www.dafont.com/new.php
after downloading copy and paste the files in android studio's font directory.